# What is "Blog Mode" and "Sticky" in StumbleUpon?

Tags: stumbleupon

When I create a new favorite in StumbleUpon, is see two checkboxes `Blog Mode` and `Sticky` but no definition of what they mean or why I might want to use them.

What do these choices mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the difference posting a normal review of a site you've stumbled or a blog post just to shoot the breeze. The sticky option is like forums or blog welcome notices, tacked on and sitting high atop the rest of the posts.

> Blog mode let's you make a post that is other than a review of a stumble - a regular "blog" entry, if you like.
>
> Sticky mode makes a review or a blog entry stay at the top of your reviews page.
>
> [StumbleUpon Community Support Staff](http://getsatisfaction.com/stumbleupon/topics/what_is_the_different_between_blog_mode_and_sticky_mode)

You'll also see that when you select the **Blog mode** checkbox, the label "URL" changes to "Title" to go along with the blog post.